# How to automatically post on a forum after a random interval?

Tags: automation, macros, forum

I am a regular user of the forum: http://forums.vr-zone.com/

Currently, I am selling a laptop on the marketplace. As it gets very crowded in there, I have to manually bump my post every few minutes to keep it on the front page. Bumping is allowed on that forum but is very tedious.

Is there any way I can automate this? I know some JavaScript and Java, if it helps.

This is the operation that I want to execute:

1. Go to the web page of my post.
2. Enter the word "bump" into the quick reply box.
3. Click "Post Quick Reply" button.
4. Repeat after a random interval of every hour or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

- Using developer tools (F12) on chrome or ie, or [tamper data addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) on firefox find out the post request sent when you click the button.

  - Open the page
  - Press F12
  - Click on network capture tab
  - Click on start capturing
  - Fill the text field and press the button
  - You will find http post request in captured traffic
  - See the source
- Now you can write a script that sends the post request every hour

I have not done that on Java script or Java (Ref: [JQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)). Have done similar stuff using python and C++. You could search for mechanize library in python. For C++ https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112084

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a macro software that moves the mouse and clicks the appropriate button at specified time intervals. (Autohotkeys?).

In order to continue using your computer while this happens, use a virtual machine.